# Replacing old ceiling fan with light with a simple dimmer switch!

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I have 4 blue wires and one yellow wire in a wire nut on the right side as your looking at the box and 2 blue wires on the left!  My dimmer switch has 2 black wires on the top in the back and 1 green on the bottom!!
How do I wire this dimmer switch????

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes involved? I take it you've replaced the fan with a plain light fixture for that matter?

Comment: How was the old switch wired?

Comment: I wish to connect a dimmer switch that has two black wires at the top of switch and a green wire on the bottom!! Need to know what wires from the descriptions in the comment above do I need to connect to this dimmer switch!!

Comment: No photos available cause my son already had disconnected the wires from the fan/light switch. There is only one box involved here, 4 blue wires and one yellow wire and on the other side of box is two blue wires! Test meters showed hot yellow wire and when touch to the two blue wires individually on the left side of box it tested 120 volts now the yellow wire is with the other 4 blue wires on the right side of the box it didn’t test for voltage when touched to those other 4 wires next to it! The yellow wire is the only wire that lite the light in my wire tester – Thomas 8 hours ago

Comment: ThreePhaseEel is asking for photos of the boxes as they are now.  We know it's too late to get "as they were before" pix :) rest assured this comes up in almost every question :) As for the second box, ThreePhaseEel is referring to the box containing the switch that controls the former fan, where presumably you want to install the dimmer. Don't disconnect anything there - just pull whatever's there aside and use flash so we can see into the back of the box.  It's fine to wildly overexpose the wall, we need to see wire colors and groupings in the back of the box.